# Doja Cat - Paint the Town Red Chord Progression

Tags: chords, chord-progressions

What is the functional explanation of the chord progression in the Doja Cat song Paint the Town Red?

I think it's in G minor and is an alternating `Gm7` `Am7` progression.

Where does the `Am7` come from?

G minor would have an `Adim`, right?

Is it actually a `ii` `iii` from F major?

Edit: There's a blog post [here](https://www.stereogum.com/2236347/a-composer-breaks-down-the-music-theory-behind-doja-cats-1-hit-paint-the-town-red/columns/in-theory/) discussing this very topic.

Comment: I remember asking a similar question on here many years ago. As a beginner, I found it difficult to end the confusion I had around a progression containing a chord in different key from the others. Music is complicated and I was rigidly trying to hold onto anything to keep things as simple as possible.
Now I'll play a progression which includes chords which I don't think are even documented. I just like the sound of it.

Comment: @JamieButterworth - oh, that everyone had that mindset...

Comment: @JamieButterworth I appreciate your comment. When we first learn about diatonic harmony and harmony in general the skies part and the choir sings a beautiful major chord and we think: “This is It!”, only to discover later that it’s just a guide and explanation of how some chord progressions work and not a set of rules to live by. ;)

Answer (score 11):

This progression is sampled from a Dionne Warwick’s “Walk On By” written by Burt Bacharach and Hal David in the early 1960’s.

It is not uncommon to use a ii chord with a natural 5th in pop music in a minor key. “Moondance” by Van Morrison is another well known example (Am-Bm on the verses). It can be justified with the melodic minor scale like @Aaron mentioned or it can also be justified by thinking of it as G Dorian.

The bottom line is there is not nearly as much concern for harmonic function in pop music as there is in more traditional styles.

Comment: +1 for the last para. alone!

Answer (score 4):

Here we go again! Songs do not have to only possess chords that are diatonic!! Who spreads this misinformation?!

Playing an F chord after shows that the key would indeed be F major, not that that is ever reached - but it sounds like home more than any other.

So, yes, it's ii and iii of key F, possibly attributable to being in *G Dorian*. Which of course, is made up from the parent key F major.

Just dug out a version, written in key C, but that ends on the aforementioned F! It's by Bacharach and David, so will be a 'good song' anyway! Just taking that line doesn't really help find a key - far more of the chord sequence would be needed, and it's not available in the version quoted.

Answer (score 3):

Although the *key* of G minor has Eb (so, yes, Adim or Amin7b5), in practice, G minor can also include E natural and F#. F# is the leading tone, so often inserted into minor to create stronger cadences, and E is then used to smooth the path from D to F# — D-E-F# being considered "smoother" than D-Eb-F#. The resulting scale is referred to as "melodic minor" (ascending only, descending one reverts to F natural and Eb, which is discussed elsewhere on this site).

Comment: "Classical melodic minor" as opposed to "Jazz melodic minor"...

Comment: Sometimes E natural is used not to "smooth the path to F sharp" but to provide a perfect fifth above D.  It can also be used because the piece supposedly in a minor key is in the Dorian mode.